# Powershell key=value output

Tags: powershell

I searched for answer to this before posting, so I apologise in advance if it's here and I can't find it!

I'm using Powershell to pull a heap of data from my Exchange server and it is put into a hashtable.

I have no problem formatting this hashtable to suit my own reporting needs, but now I want to put this data into Splunk (I know about the Splunk Exchange App, this is for different needs).

So Splunk can pull the data in without any pre-processing work I need it to look like the below.

```
timestamp key=value,key=value,key=value,key=value
timestamp key=value,key=value,key=value,key=value
timestamp key=value,key=value,key=value,key=value
timestamp key=value,key=value,key=value,key=value
timestamp key=value,key=value,key=value,key=value
```

Comment: I'm looking how to format a hashtable to that output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ht = @{one=1; two=2; three=3}
$KeysAndValues = $ht.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object { '{0}={1}' -f $_.Key,$_.Value }
'{0:MM/dd/yyyy} {1}' -f (Get-Date),($KeysAndValues -join ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's build output the output string with a StringBuilder.

```
$sb=new-object Text.StringBuilder
# Append timestamp, here from system time
[void]$sb.Append("{0} " -f [datetime]::now.tostring("u"))
# Populate sample hashtable with some data
$ht = @{"foo"="oof"; "bar"="rab"; "baz"="zab"; "qux"="xug" }
# Enumerate the hashtable by sorted names just for fun
$ht.GetEnumerator() | sort name | % { 
# Append keys and values to the stringbuilder
  [void]$sb.Append($("{0}={1}," -f $_.Name, $_.Value))
}
# Get rid of the tailing comma
[void]$sb.Remove($sb.Length-1, 1)
# Print output
$sb.ToString()
```